# calling action when button clicked

Tags: php, yii, onclick, action

I want to call an action when a button is clicked.
I have a button for accept a request, so when I click this button I want to call the action `actionRequestAcceptence`, but this action is being called automatically without clicking the button.

here is the code:

```
CHtml::imageButton($src.'accept.ico', array('id'=>'accept', 'onClick'=>$this->actionRequestAcceptence($modelr[$j]->idRequest, $model->idUser),'confirm'=>'are you sure?','style'=>'width:32px;height:32px'));
```

so where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246361/how-to-create-a-link-with-confirmation-dialog-using-yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing strange since your are calling `actionRequestAcceptence` instead of building a link to this action... You should try :

```
$imageButton = CHtml::imageButton($src.'accept.ico', array('style'=>'width:32px;height:32px'));
$url = array('requestAcceptence','idRequest'=>$modelr[$j]->idRequest,'idUser'=>$model->idUser);
echo CHtml::link($imageButton, $url, array('id'=>'accept', 'confirm'=>'are you sure?'));
```

You should modifiy `idRequest` and `idUser` depending on your action params names.